# Pointer warning that i dont understand

Tags: c

I try to direct the user to different forums, and then ask him to choose a block. But I have several errors when I compile, I am not familiar with my pointers.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_NOM 10 

typedef struct Place {
    char seat[15] ; 
}Place; 

typedef struct Rang{
    int rang        ; 
    Place une_place ; 
}Rang; 

typedef struct Bloc {
    int bloc     ; 
    Rang un_rang ; 
}Bloc; 

typedef struct Stade {

    char nom[MAX_NOM]     ; 
    char tribune[MAX_NOM] ;
    Bloc un_bloc          ; 
}Stade; 

int main()
{

    int numbloc = 0  ; 
    Stade unstade ; 
    Bloc unbloc[21];
    Rang unrang[4];
    Place uneplace[99];

 printf("Nom de la tribune         :")       ;
 scanf("%s", &unstade.tribune)               ;
 
 if(strcmp(unstade.tribune, "Nord" == "1" ))
 {
    // printf("Dans quel bloc voulez-vous réserver une place : ")   ; 
    // scanf("%d", &numbloc)                                        ;

    // while ((numbloc < 0) & (numbloc >21) )
    // {
    //     printf("Merci de saisir un numéro de bloc entre 0 et 22")  ; 
    // }
 }
 else if (strcmp(unstade.tribune, "Sud" == "1" ))
 {
     printf("SUUUUD"); 

 }
 else if(strcmp(unstade.tribune, "Est" == "1"))
 {
     printf("ESSSST") ; 

 }
 else if (strcmp(unstade.tribune, "Ouest" == "1" ))
 {
     printf("OUESSST") ; 
 }
 else{
     printf ("Le nom de la tribune doit être Nord, Sud, Est ou Ouest") ;
 }

}
```

i dont know if its because the
scanf("%s", &unstade.tribune)               ; OR
scanf("%s", unstade.tribune)               ;
[image: I have this message]

Comment: Its a type-thing. `&unstade.tribune` is `char (*)[MAX_NOM]`, The format specifier `%s` expects `char *`. I.e. you should be using `unstade.tribune`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change this:

```
scanf("%s", &unstade.tribune);
```

To this:

```
scanf("%s", unstade.tribune);
```

The `%s` format specifier expects a char array or a char pointer, but not a pointer to an array.

This is not how you compare a string for equality:

```
if(strcmp(unstade.tribune, "Nord" == "1" ))
```

But this is:

```
if (strcmp(unstade.tribune, "Nord") == 0)
```

`strcmp` returns an integer `0` to indicate equality between both parameters.

Answer (score 1):

`strcmp(unstade.tribune, "Nord" == "1")` is completelly wrong. Why?

`"Nord" == "1"` compares the address of the string literal `"Nord"` with the address of the string literal `"1"`. They are for sure different. So the result of this operation is zero. You pass this zero to `strcpy` as the second parameter.

`strcmp(unstade.tribune, 0)`. The second parameter is integer which is being converted to pointer to char. Thus warning. `strcmp` will compare the `unstade.tribune` with NULL pointer which UB (Undefined Behaviour) and it is very likely to result in segfault.